# Travis-ci failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3

Tags: android, travis-ci

I builded my [library](https://github.com/emrekose26/CopyExternalDB) `Android build-tools version to 23.0.3` in travis-ci but building is failure like below

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3
```

in my `.travis.yml` like below

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-23.0.3
    - android-23
    - extra
```

and this is the `travis-ci build logs` [here](https://travis-ci.org/emrekose26/CopyExternalDB/builds/148836239)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update sdk tools and platform tools due to the versions used by the VM are outdated and the build tools you are trying to use require them. This change will install latest tools:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-23.0.3
    - android-23
    - extra
```

Further information [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android#Overview) and [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5648).